# elemMatch combined with other query fields in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Sample data:

```
[{
    "_id": "529532bee0ea703842000003",
    "patientId": "123",
    "name": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "family": "Smith"
    },
    "diet": [{
        "_id": "1",
        "mealtType": "Break Fast",
        "timeofMeal": "2013-11-12T03:05:06.000Z",
        "status": "I",
        "calorie": {
            "value": 500,
            "unit": "cals"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "mealtType": "Break Fast",
        "timeofMeal": "2013-11-12T03:05:06.000Z",
        "status": "A",
        "calorie": {
            "value": 550,
            "unit": "cals"
        }
    }]
}]
```

I wanted to fetch only active (status 'A') embedded document (diet document) for a given patientId ('123') using mongoose in node.

Here is my mongoose query:

```
query.where('patientId', 123)
     .where('diet').elemMatch(function(elem) {
    elem.where('_id', 1)
    elem.where('status', 'A')
})
```

Mongoose generated below query, which is brining all elements from embedded array diet for patient.

```
Mongoose: patients.find({ diet: { '$elemMatch': { _id: '1', status: 'A' } }, patientId: '123' })
```

The above query fetches all sub documents irrespective of status at Mongo Shell too.

They only way I could make it work at Mongo shell by wrapping each where condition {'patientId':'123'},{'diet' : { $elemMatch : {'status':'A'} }}.

```
db.patients.find({'patientId':'123'},{'diet' : { $elemMatch : {'status':'A'} }} ).pretty() // works fine
```

How can I force Mongoose to enclose each query field in a curly braces or any other thoughts?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It's not very clear. Essentially, you're wondering how to write a mongoose query that will accomplish the same thing as Query1? Please clarify what you want to return.

Comment: EmptyArsenal, I've updated my post: I wanted to fetch only active (status 'A') embedded document (diet document) for a given patientId (search field at root level document) using mongoose in node.

Answer (score 12):

In your query that works, the `$elemMatch` object is not another query condition, but is the output field selection (i.e. projection) parameter to `find`.

To do the same in Mongoose, you'd do something like:

```js
PatientsModel.find({patientId: '123'}, {diet: {$elemMatch: {'status': 'A'}}}, cb)
```

OR

```js
PatientsModel
    .where('patientId', '123')
    .select({diet: {$elemMatch: {'status': 'A'}})
    .exec(cb);
```